# C# VSTO Add-in Excel: What is the name of this Excel Super-Tab Control and how to make it? (Contextual Tab or Tool Tab)

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

In Excel (On Windows), there is a kind of a **Super-Tab appearing on top of certain Tabs**:

### «Drawing Tools» Super-Tab:

When you click on a Graphic object then, this one appears:
[image]

### «Table Tools» Super-Tab:

When you click inside of a Table object then this kind of a Super-Tab appears:
[image]

### So my Questions are:

> - What is the **technical name of that Super-Tab**?
>     ---> Special thanks to @TimWilliam. He was the one who gave its name: It is a [Contextual Tab Set](https://www.google.com/search?q=contextual%20tab%20set&sxsrf=ALeKk01TwLJ9BJHsJac-T5AaVGgnoAHcNg:1586850807978&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw9-H1t-foAhXEQhUIHWvgAbwQ_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1828&bih=648#imgrc=nf6i-IV1fJHH4M)
> - And **how to program something like that** in VSTO Add-in please? (Anything related to it)

Your responses are much appreciated!

Comment: [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019) and, about coding, notice the link at the bottom to [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs)

Comment: @Luuk, thanks for your response. I know and I have already built my own Custom Tab and the Ribbon with it. But what intrigues me is this kind of **Super-Tab** in Excel that seems only be available for Build-in Excel Tabs. I wonder if we can have access to it or build one like that one. How and where could be the interesting question

Comment: ... As I show on the Picture, the arrows are pointing on the **Super-Tab** (Green Background) not to the normal tabs below it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-chart-controls-to-worksheets?view=vs-2019  (i am not going to use it, you do want know how to do it, maybe you do the searching?, just asking...)

Comment: Thanks @Luuk, if not today, may be in the future somebody will give a way to and method to use it. I spent a whole day to search for this then I posted the question over here. This is the kind of question I really do not have answer yet!

Comment: "contextual tab set" is the term to search on.  But I don't think you can create new ones.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you so much! You solved the first equation permitting us to move forward. I updated the Question including your Valid answer :) . It is indeed called **contectual tab set**. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering to my Question so I do not lose all the important answers and research I got till now:

### 1. The name of that kind of Super-Tab:

> - The credit goes to @TimWilliams. The name of that Special tab is [Contextual Tab](https://www.google.com/search?q=Contextual%20Tab&hl=en&sxsrf=ALeKk02VS__sl7W3lPPc2XxZbkfwZqUqvg:1586851661646&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp1OmMu-foAhX7URUIHUxOBhEQ_AUoAXoECA4QAw&biw=1828&bih=648) or also called [Tool Tab](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/learn-microsoft-excel/the-ribbon.cfm).
> - Here it is an official Information from Microsoft entitled: [Ribbons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/cmd-ribbons)
>     [image]

---

### 2. How to  program the Contextual Tab?

- I am still looking for How to program this one. At least Microsoft already explains about it here >>> [2.2.41 tabSet (Contextual Tab Set)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/90a00968-4747-4512-8601-b61440747033)
- I found 2 new interesting discussions and information over here [Adding custom contextual tabs to Ribbon UI](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/adding-custom-contextual-tabs-to-ribbon-ui/5fc31ea5-2db4-4aef-9f59-3e7154db7b05) and over here [Ribbon: Contextual tab on application page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/135030c5-9abb-4773-8ecf-5b76cef6ee15/ribbon-contextual-tab-on-application-page?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious). But they are all for **ASP.NET**.
- Here as well is the List of **Tool Tab** available on Excel: [Tool Tab Available on Excel](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/ribbon/contextual-tabs.htm)
- But once I found a working solution, I will share here as well for the advancement of our work.

Keep it up dear Programmers and stay blessed!

@TsiriniainaRakotonirina